# Java Server:Conferencing between lecturer and students by broadcasting

Tags: java, client, broadcast

Say there are 2000 connections to a server.
10% of them are lecturers and lead a course, and at the same time conducting an online lecture. The remaining 90% of users are students who watch the lecture.

What is the best way to broadcast this? Going through the server as lecturer sends the information to the server, and server refers to students? Or should students directly connect to speakers and have them broadcast information to the students without going through the server?

Comment: Students directly connecting to speakers requires the latter to act as a server, which might lead to problems, if they are behind a firewall/NAT-router or in some mobile network.

Comment: I totally agree with you? But which one to choose? Which is the lesser evil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving one valid answer for your question not possible, since there are plenty of aspects unknown. Some of these questions immediately popping into my mind are:

- the type of data (i.e. is some preprocessing needed by the server)
- the amount of data (i.e. simple chat vs. video stream)
- network structure (do they all connect from within the same network, or freely from anywhere; is multicasting an option?; can lecturers connect via mobile networks; firewalls/NAT?; bandwidth?)
- monitoring/logging/recording of exchanged data (is a log/recording of the exchanged data/lecture required)
- security constraints (that might forbid direct connection to a server running potentially untrusted code)
- scaling requirements (could 2000 connections become 10000 in near future)

Lecturing including video streaming is probably a blocker for the distributed approach, since a lecturer probably can't handle streams to 9 or more students. However, in this case, a "simple server" would also not be sufficient (maybe a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)). Also NAT might be a big issue, although there are [different techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) for traversal.

I would tend to the server-centric-approach, it seems to raise fewer issues when the client-environment can not be controlled, even if it might (potentially heavily) increase the requirements on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Will scout more about what you told me.  
2000 people online calculate it as the ultimate bad option.---
If there is more people of 2 000 , I think that university / school will be able to separate them into 2 or more  servers to the faculties.  Create this app I want to surprise my lecturer on programming.  Again, thanks for the reply.